# RecyclerView scrolls slowly and with lag on Samsung note 4

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I have a RecyclerView that each row of that has a GridLayout. I inserted some rows (about 10) in the RecyclerView. It scrolls smoothly in Nexus 5 and Nexus 7 and Sony. But when I run it on Samsung Note 4, it scrolls very slowly and with lots of lag!! 
This is my layout for each row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:orientation="vertical"
    app:columnCount="4"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/start_time_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="0"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:text="test"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_rowSpan="3"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical|fill"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="test"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/event_icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|fill"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/button_material_dark"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:text="test"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_supervisor_account_black_24dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/end_time_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:text="test"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:textColor="@color/button_material_dark"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="test"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        app:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_column="3"
        android:src="@mipmap/location"/>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/time_progressbar"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnSpan="3"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="100"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:indeterminate="false" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical|fill"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:text="test"

        />



</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

How can I fix this problem?